# Gateway MX6440 CPU Upgrade

Tags: cpu, laptop-repair

I have received an a Gateway MX6440 laptop as a freebie, but I'm interested in upgrading its AMD Turion 64 ML-32 (socket 754) to something faster (and more cache).  I know the range of processors that could work based on the family list in Wikipedia.  However, this computer has the stock bios, and any updates I haven't applied from Gateway doesn't specify processor support.  I'm looking to go to at least a 2.2 (ML-40).  Has anybody upgraded the processor in this model or other in the series success or failure and do you happen to have any guides handy for working with the heat sink?  Any Googling I have done keeps hitting RAM marketers.

**Update**

Computer died before I had a chance to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to replace it with similar processor in terms of power consumption. ML-40 could be good option because it needs 25W and ML-32 needs 24W.

Of course, they have to be from same processor series and those two are.

Basically, when AMD make processors, all of them are made at same place, but some of them turn out to run stable on higher frequency so they are sold for more money. That is why it should not be a problem if you replace it.

I would only check if your BIOS is hard-locked to that CPU. Maybe you can contact Gateway support?

Comment: Thanks for the info, it isn't new to me, but hopefully help somebody new.  I haven't thought of contacting Gateway support though, I'm sure they are going to say that they don't provide support for this hardware anymore.